# How to add a function to dropdown list?

Tags: processing

I've added a drop down list in processing using controlp5 library. I want to transmit data serially to Arduino when certain item is selected in the list. How to add the control for this purpose?

Here's my code:

```java
void setup{
d1 = cp5.addDropdownList("color")
.setPosition(((width/4)-50), ((height/2)-40))
.setBackgroundColor(color(37, 126, 214))
.setFont(font1)
.setItemHeight(25)
.setBarHeight(20)
.addItem("red ", d1)
.addItem("blue ", d1)
.addItem("green ", d1)
 }
```

I want to send a character 'r','b','g' to Arduino when each item is selected respectively. Suggest me how to write the code for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown list is deprecated as the author says in the example, I think the simplest way is to implement ScrollableList, which is more flexible, and send the data though Serial Port to Arduino.

```
// Import java utils, for the list to add to the scrollable list
import java.util.*;


// Import ControlP5 library and declare it
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5;

// Import the Serial port and declare it
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);

  // Initialize the Serial port
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);-

  // Initialize the dropdown list
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  List l = Arrays.asList("red", "green", "blue");
  /* add a ScrollableList, by default it behaves like a DropdownList */
  cp5.addScrollableList("dropdown")
    .setPosition(100, 100)
    .setSize(200, 100)
    .setBarHeight(20)
    .setItemHeight(20)
    .addItems(l)
    ;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
}

// Dropdown callback function fromthe ScrollableList, triggered when you select an item
void dropdown(int n) {
  /* request the selected item based on index n and store in a char */
  String string = cp5.get(ScrollableList.class, "dropdown").getItem(n).get("name").toString();
  char c = string.charAt(0);

  // Write the char to the serial port
  myPort.write(c);
}
```

On the Arduino side

```
char val; // Data received from the serial port

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) { // If data is available to read,
    val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your program.